# Can anyone explain it to me why correlation between the variables (X and Y) is what it is?

Tags: correlation, pearson-r

[image]The figure on left looks less scattered (the axis is compressed) but has lower correlation. Whereas, the figure on right has multiple association for same value of X (i.e. X=0).

Comment: I would guess that the scatterplot is hiding the fact that there are lots of points somwhere. Perhaps on the right there are many points on [0, 0]

Comment: Why would such an overlap lead to a high correlation? I am really finding it very non-intuitive with my limited knowledge of statistics.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of data and there's a lot of overlap of points. This obscures any visual relationship that can be detected from the data. To reconcile the correlation values with the data, you can create a plot of point density (e.g., [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093935/r-scatter-plot-symbol-color-represents-number-of-overlapping-points)). Perhaps a bit more simply I'd suggest making the point translucent. If you can color points using RGBA, then reduce the alpha channel to make the points translucent. This will allow you to more clearly see areas of the graph with higher and lower densities of points. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will check what's happening with the overlaps.